# What are the different combinations for the runes?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor, realms-of-the-diggle-god

In the Diggle Gods expansion, there is a room that has three runes and a lever.  The runes are pillar, growth and decay, and scrutiny.  They can be placed in spots in the floor and a lever pulled.  What are the different combinations for the runes and what do they produce?

For example - from top to bottom - pillar growth scrutiny produces a food vending machine when the lever is pulled.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Pillar Growth Scrutiny = Food Dispenser
Pillar Scrutiny Growth = Bolt Dispenser
Growth Scrutiny pillar = Thrown Weapon Dispenser
Growth Pillar Scrutiny = Craft Dispenser
Scrutiny Growth Pillar = Drink Dispenser
Scrutiny Pillar Growth = no effect (runes remain on the ground)
```